# How to reflect changes of PHP variable in JQuery / HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `$return` in php that changes according to what was posted on the form. Here's the JQuery & HTML Code:

```
$(function() {
           $('#query_sort').on('change', function(event) {
               var query_sort = $(this).val();
               alert(query_sort);

               if(query_sort) {
                   $.ajax({
                       method: "POST",
                       url: "/_php/nds/return_criteria_checkbox.php",
                       data: {query_sort: query_sort}
                   })
                       .done(function(data){
                           alert(<?php echo $query; ?>);
                           $('#dashboard_table_tbody').html(<?php echo $return; ?>);
                   });
               }
            });
        });
```

And for my `tbody`,

```html
<tbody id = "dashboard_table_tbody" style = "height: 10px;">
    <?php echo $return; ?>
</tbody>
```

Even when I change my form, which gets auto-submitted when it is changed (without refreshing the webpage) the `$return` changes too, but the HTML page doesn't reflect that change. What Can I do to have it update?

Comment: php is a server side language, you can not do that without refreshing the page. you have to use js

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro Yeah, I'm not asking that. `$return` be changed, that's fine, but how do I reflect that on the webpage without refreshing?

Comment: this is the problem : $('#dashboard_table_tbody').html(<?php echo $return; ?>)

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro That works the first time it's loaded, but once `$return` changes, it doesn't reflect the change in `$return`.

Comment: exact, cause $return is PHP code, and PHP is server side language, as i said

Comment: but once $return changes. How you are changing the  $return?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh The PHP script changes it by an AJAX request shown above.

Comment: You cannot use PHP inside your AJAX. If you need further help it might be best to provide an example of the data that is returned to AJAX.

Comment: One of the data that is returned is `query_data = time_asec`, which is processed in the php file and returns html code for tables from the MySQL query.,

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing client-side and server-side technologies.
PHP is a server side language, JS is (also) a client-side language.

To do what you need you have to use javascript.
Your return_criteria_checkbox.php file should return something like that:

**return_criteria_checkbox.php**

```
echo json_encode(['return_from_php' => 'something you want to return']);
```

You HTML file becomes:

```
$(function() {
       $('#query_sort').on('change', function(event) {
           var query_sort = $(this).val();
           alert(query_sort);

           if(query_sort) {
               $.ajax({
                   method: "POST",
                   url: "/_php/nds/return_criteria_checkbox.php",
                   data: {query_sort: query_sort}
               })
                   .done(function(data){
                       $('#dashboard_table_tbody').html(data.return_from_php);
               });
           }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return data in json form from the URL you are posting data through Ajax and slight changes in JQuery function as the way I have done below and you are set to go.
Below Lines of code is for taking input from Html and submitting it without refreshing the page with the help of JQuery and Ajax. We will also need to create a php file called 'return_criteria_checkbox.php' and sending back JSON data to this page.

```
<input type="text" id="query_sort">
<p id="dashboard_table_tbody" style="height: 10px;"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#query_sort').change(function(event) {
    var query_sort = $(this).val();
    // alert(query_sort);
    if(query_sort) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "return_criteria_checkbox.php",
            data: {query_sort: query_sort},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
                {
                    var replaced_Data = data.replace(/\"/g, "");
                    $('#dashboard_table_tbody').html(replaced_Data);
                    $('#query_sort').val('');
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Below are the lines of code for `return_criteria_checkbox.php` file:

```
<?php
// Fetching Values From Ajax URL
$posted_data = $_POST['query_sort'];
echo json_encode($posted_data);
// You can also insert data to database using below lines of code
// $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
// $db = mysql_select_db("mydba", $connection);
// if (isset($_POST['name1'])) {
// $query = mysql_query("insert into form_element(posted_data) values('$posted_data')"); //Insert Query
// echo "Form Submitted succesfully";
// }
// mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

Use the Above code and you are good to go.